# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method

Tags: java-8

I got this exception when upgrading from `java 7` to `java 8`:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getNumberFormatData(Ljava/util/Locale;)Ljava/util/ResourceBundle

I'm using `jre1.8.0_31`

Comment: Please include the code where this error occurred.

Comment: ERROR 14:43:43,574 [LogLevel.java:84] - at org.atdl4j.ui.swing.widget.SwingNullableSpinner$NumberEditorNull.getDefaultPattern(SwingNullableSpinner.java:184) 
ERROR 14:43:43,574 [LogLevel.java:84] - at org.atdl4j.ui.swing.widget.SwingNullableSpinner$NumberEditorNull.<init>(SwingNullableSpinner.java:190)

Comment: I checked the method code source in both jdk 7 and 8 and it changed from static to non-static, that's why I get his issue, but still don't know how to fix this!

Comment: If you edit your question to include your old (working) code looks like, and also mention this change from static to non-static, it would make your question a lot more presentable and answerable.

Comment: Simple to fix: *don’t use `sun.*` packages* [as being said for twenty years or so](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html)

Comment: so need to update atdl4j jar??

Comment: Right, just update; apparently this issue [was fixed on 17 Oct 2013](https://github.com/atdl4j/atdl4j/commit/696e7bbb35101bd3c2c74eed63be8c98487b08dd#diff-ae7ddf1fde2b3fa81afea9688a805b67L22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this:
update atdl4j.jar
you can download it from Here's [a link]: (https://github.com/atdl4j/atdl4j)